# Difference between location and redirect in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

What is the use of res.location() method? I can use res.redirect() to redirect to a particular URL and i cannot see any change if i use res.location() before res.redirect()

Answer (score 45, accepted):

They are very similar in their description, but one does much more. The easiest way to see the difference is look at [the source](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/2f8ac6726fa20ab5b4a05c112c886752868ac8ce/lib/response.js#L826).

`res.location` just sets the response header. It does not set a response status code or close the response, so you can write a response body if you want, and you have to call `res.end()` on your own after.

`res.redirect` on the other hand sets the status to 302, sets the header (using `res.location`) and sends a nice response body saying that the user is being redirected, and renders a link if their browser doesn't automatically redirect them for some reason.

Comment: Thanks loganfsmyth :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Kinda off topic but worth a mention if you're going to add  res.redirect its a good thing to keep in mind the type of redirects. 301 vs 302 as loganfsmyth said, res.redirect sets the status to 302 by default but this is bad SEO. To change the status code for res.redirect add 301 then the route to redirect to.

Ex-> `res.redirect(301, 'new-page');`