# flash-connect into express with jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I cant undestand why it dont working. I make into express route

```
    User.createUser(newUser, function(err,user){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(user);
});

req.flash('info', 'Flash Message Added');

res.location('/');
res.redirect('/');
```

and into view

```
    - if (messages.info)
     .message.info
       span= messages.info
```

i followed [this example into npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-flash). What i do wrong?

Comment: i solved this problem like this but i cant undestand how it works...  into jade file i used `!= messages()` and [connect-flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash) . I found this example into eduonix but cant understand...

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling both `res.location`, and `res.redirect`, you're essentially performing two redirects. Your `req.flash` message only sticks around for the current page request, so it would only be visible on the first redirect. Redirecting the second time clears your flash messages, which is why it may not be showing. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677940/difference-between-location-and-redirect-in-node-js) for the differences between `res.location` and `res.redirect`.