# why use res.location before res.redirect?

Tags: node.js, express

I was recently come across this code:

```
res.location('/');
res.redirect('/');
```

I don't know why even use res.location?

Comment: You can see this ans, it's well explained. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677940/difference-between-location-and-redirect-in-node-js

Answer (score 1):

`res.location` just sets the response header.

`res.redirect` on the other hand sets the status to 302.

See the difference in [the source](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/2f8ac6726fa20ab5b4a05c112c886752868ac8ce/lib/response.js#L826).

Comment: I still don't get it! what's the advantage of using res.location?

Comment: @AshrafBawer please check this link you will understand the differences:  https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-redirect